# Multiple connections automatic switching

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, ppp

I'm currently working on a very bare systemd based embedded OS.

I have ppp and wifi as means of connecting to the internet. I need it to switch from ppp to wifi when it's available. Kind of like you do an an Android phone or an iPhone.

What would be the best way to achieve this without network.manager?
Are there any kind of bash examples or linux system level services that can do this?

Comment: Do you have `wpa_supplicant`? (You'd need it anyway for WPA encrypted WLAN). You'll get both signals when it connects, and hooks to execute scripts. Read the docs.

Comment: Yes. I'm using wpa_supplicant for connecting to wlans. Where can I get said docs? Any links you can provide. Can said hooks be implemented in services?

Comment: See e.g. "Using wpa_cli to run external program on connect/disconnect" in the README (local docs, or http://w1.fi/cgit/hostap/plain/wpa_supplicant/README). I've forgotten most of the details, and would need to re-read it myself, and not sure if this is the best hook for you, or if another variant would be better (I remember there's various stuff in `ifup`/`ifdown`). When you figure out the details, remember you can also answer your own question on stack overflow (and accept the answer).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much. I used the wpa_cli -a mode and modified the script to dial and hang up the PPP. It has it's own setup scripts pon and poff located in "/usr/bin/". I just called those when wifi has connected or lost connection. The thing even does on the fly routing for me.